# Getting ComponentTemplate Metadata from .NET Template code

Tags: 2011, cme, templating

I set some data into ComponentTemplate using Metadata schema.
And I'm trying to fetch this data through .NET code, but I can't find some related variables in engine, package to do this.
Could someone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Because it is basically as simple as using the `ComponentTemplate.Metadata` and `ComponentTemplate.MetadataSchema` properties in your `ItemFields` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
var componentTemplateId =  package.GetSources("Component.ComponentTemplate")[0].GetValue("ID");
var componentTemplate = (ComponentTemplate) engine.GetSession().GetObject(componentTemplateId);
var metadata = componentTemplate.Metadata;
```

And example how to read a single field from Metadata:

```
ItemFields metadataFields = new ItemFields(componentTemplate.Metadata, componentTemplate.MetadataSchema);
TextField myTextField = (TextField)metadataFields["MyTextFieldName"];
string myTextFieldValue = myTextField.Value;
```

This should get you going until someone will post a simpler solution

Comment: I've tried your solution. Unfortunately, `package.GetSources("Component.ComponentTemplate")` returns empty array.

Comment: BTW, I've found the better way to get component template metadata: `engine.PublishingContext.ResolvedItem.Template.Metadata`

Comment: You should probably check if that's not `null` before trying to load it, but yes, that's how I would read it too.